# How to redirect from outside of the component in react ionic framwork

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I am trying to redirect my app on a condition. If it's login as a teacher then it must redirect to teachers profile otherwise it should redirect to student profile and if it's not login then it must redirect to login.

```
(() => {
if (isLoggedIn() !== "false")
  AppRoutes.push({
    path: isLoggedIn() === "teacher" ? "/tabs/home" : "/",
    exact: true,
    Component: isLoggedIn() === "teacher" ? TeachersProfile : ITCStudent,
  });
else
  AppRoutes.push({
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    Component: Login,
  });
})();
```

This code is setting up the default component but i want to redirect to the profile page

Answer (score 0):

Ionic React 5 and 6 are using React Router 5 (not React Router 6).

So one way is to redirect with `useHistory()`.

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push('/redirect-path');
```

I'm not sure what AppRoutes is in your example, but if you have defined all your routes in , then you can just push to the path; you don't need to be passing the component.